# JFileChooser wont die?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

I have a JFrame that opens a JFileChooser via an action event.

When this JFrame is disposed and the user opens up a new one and selects the JFileChooser they get one JFileChooser popup for each JFrame that has ever been open(and disposed).

Is this a common issue?

```
btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    filets = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String shortName = file.getName();
                            if(shortName.length() > 9 ){
                                String roar = shortName.substring(0, 9);
                                String shortErName = roar+"...";
                                btnBrowse.setText(shortErName);                             
                            }
                            else {
                                btnBrowse.setText(shortName);
                            }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error Getting File!");
                }

            }
        });
```

And my browse button:

```
btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    filets = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String shortName = file.getName();
                            if(shortName.length() > 9 ){
                                String roar = shortName.substring(0, 9);
                                String shortErName = roar+"...";
                                btnBrowse.setText(shortErName);                             
                            }
                            else {
                                btnBrowse.setText(shortName);
                            }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error Getting File!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is this code located (is it in the constructor of the Jframe)?

Comment: It is in the constructor, I have one class called Frame that basicly builds the JFrame then makes it visable, I have another class that just calls Frame() to open a new instance, I also have my close action set to JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine what's happening is that `btnBrowse` is getting one of these `ActionListener`s added each time you create a `JFrame`, but nothing is actually removing those listeners. If it's the same `JButton` that survives the dispose of the `JFrame` -- i.e, if the button itself is located elsewhere or if it's just a member in some other class and you're reusing it -- then this is almost certainly the problem.

You could override `dispose()` on the `JFrame` and call `btnBrowse.removeActionListener()` to get rid of the listener before calling `super.dispose()`.

Comment: I added how my browse button looks.

Comment: I found that rearranging things and making the Actionlistener named instead of just "(new Action listener{" then calling "btnBrowse.removeActionListener(buttonListen)" worked perfectly. Thank you and Angelo Neuschitzer for your great answers.

Answer (score 0):

could you post some more code (and leave away the handling of the filename?) on how you create the JFrame and the JFileChooser? I think you dispose the JFrame (as in hide it from view) but don't destroy it.
So the JButton with its ActionListeners is still alive (but just not shown) and in the second run you add another ActionListener to it, so of course, a second JFileChooser is created.

edit: some code that explains what I mean

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
JButton someButton = new JButton();
void addActionListenerToButton() {
   someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       new JFileChooser().showOpenDialog(null);
   });
}

void handler() {
    myFrame.add(someButton);
    addActionListerToButton();
    myFrame.show();
    someButton.click(); // that method does not exist, it is meant as the user clicks.
    myFrame.dispose();
}

void main() {
    handler(); // thats the first run where one JFileChooser is seen
    handler(); // thats the second one, now you have two JFileChoosers.
}
```

Comment: I will paste a bit more when I get in, I assumed that dispose was not killing everything but could not find any documentation on destroying it (and possibly all children).

Comment: easy: frame = null; (of course you may want to do that on more than just the frame...)